# how "Add entries anywhere in the file"in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, mod-rewrite

Method of placing text anywhere on the file that was previously created

---

Example of pre-written text:
Hello

#### In this place I want to add a note.

‌Bye

---

What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to *overwrite* a part of the file (assuming new content is of the same length as the one that is to be overwritten), there is no way to just insert something into a file. So you have to make a new file from scratch, using one of these two methods:

- Read file, change string, write file. (Technically, you can just read the file from the place it needs to be changed till end, truncate and write till end, but reading the whole file is a bit easier to do, and unless the file is huge it won't matter that much.)
- Open file for reading, open file for writing, read and copy till the spot you want, write new stuff, continue reading and copying, close both. Rename new file to old.